# No imagecache actions available

Tags: 6, media

I have imagecache, imageapi and imageapigd enabled on my drupal 6 site. When I visit imagecache presets no actions (crop / resize et al) are available. This all seemed to work fne with the same configuration on my MAMP home box, however, this fails in production. Some other info:

```
PHP Version: 5.2.17
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.3.11
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPG Support enabled
PNG Support enabled
WBMP Support    enabled
XBM Support enabled
```

I'm stumped - any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: Did you check file permissions and ownership, as well as the existence of the data in the DB for imagecache? Also did you try un-istalling imagecache module and trying to installing it again (deleting the module folder too)?

Answer (score 2):

Did you happen to be using one of the latest 6.x-2.x-dev versions of imagecache?

I spent an entire day trying to figure this one out (because unfortunately this was the only relevant page that came up in a google search). Once I finally decided to try the 6.x-2.0-rc1 version, everything seemed to work fine.